# ImageMagick viewbox when converting SVG

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, inkscape, viewbox

I'm trying to convert an SVG file to a PNG using `convert`, where the input image has SVG artifacts *outside the document border* - this is a byproduct of sloppy artistry, and is convenient when drawing a pretty picture.

However, when I try to use ImageMagick to convert the SVG file to a rasterized PNG, `convert` **keeps** the artifacts outside the border in the result, and recalculates the SVG viewbox. This looks very ugly, and is not what I would like as a result. For instance, I would run the following command:

```
convert input.svg -depth 200 -units pixelsperinch -border 11inx17in output.png
```

The SVG document clearly has the border and viewbox defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   viewBox="0 0 990.00002 1530"
   height="17in"
   width="11in">
     ...
```

Yet `convert` treats the *entire* SVG document (artifacts and all) as the input image, recalculates the viewbox, and the resulting output is slightly skewed, in addition to the extra artifacts spilling outside the document border.

Comment: Can you post your full SVG file or some example that shows the same issue, so others can test. One issue could be that you are using the ImageMagick internal MSVG/XML renderer. RSVG delegate or standalone or Inkscape might work better. You can check if RSVG or MSVG/XML using `convert -list format` and look at the end of the line for SVG. If Inkscape is on your system, it will be used in preference to the others. Also you should put -units and -density before reading the SVG file. I think you wrote -depth 200 but mean -density 200.

Comment: Also ImageMagick does not add borders in inches, only pixels or percents of the image dimensions. If you are trying to use -border to fill out the image to those dimension, then the correct command  is -extent. But it also does not use inches. So you would need to use your density to convert inches to pixels. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#border and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent

Comment: If you put -density 200 after reading the SVG file, then it will rasterize at 72 dpi and then define the density as 200. If you put the density before reading the SVG file, then it will rasterize at 200 dpi and make your output larger.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't paste the input image - it's very rich. But, the `-extent` option, and option re-ordering seems to be working better, but now I have to deal with initial offset. ImageMagick is still creating a new viewbox, where 0,0 is the top left corner of the _artifacts_, not just using the svg document's natural origin.

Comment: Try adding +repage after reading the SVG file.  Can you use `convert -format` to see which SVG renderer is being used?

Comment: That didn't work either - here is my current command: `convert -density 200 -units pixelsperinch input.svg +repage -extent 2200x3400 output.png`. `convert -format list |grep SVG` returns with MSVG, SVG, and SVGZ as rw+ - I'm not sure which is preferred

Comment: What do you get from `convert -list format` just for the line starting with SVG? At the right end of the line does it say MSVG or XML or RSVG? If it says MSVG/XML, then you should either install the RSVG delegate or Inkscape. If you install RSVG, you may need to reinstall ImageMagick. If you install Inkscape and ImageMagick is not ancient, then it should find that automatically. You could test with just RSVG or Inkscape directly and see if either work.

Comment: I am not an SVG expert, but see https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute. You may have to provide a transformation to get the scaling and offset to match your viewbox.

Comment: I think that's where my problem lies! I just tried to install librsvg2-dev on ubuntu 16.06 and was met with deep errors, with pango and cairo! Thank you!

Comment: Try just installing Inkscape. That is supposedly the best of the 3 renderers. And you do not need to re-install ImageMagick.

Comment: I tried, and could not compile it from source due to the errors above

Comment: Does it need to be convert, or could you also use inkscape with --export-area-page ? https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html#OPTIONS